# How to tell if a MySQL field has a default value of an empty string or no default value?

Tags: php, mysql

If we use the "DESCRIBE table" syntax in MySQL it returns information about the table including the fields and their default value.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html

However, how do we tell the difference between a field having a default value of an empty string versus not having a default value at all?

In seems in both cases it returns an empty value for the "Default" column in the output of the DESCRIBE table statement.

I would need to be able to parse the data using PHP to easily detect differences between an old table format and new table format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if MySQL will report the value as "NULL" if a default value does not exist.  This means we if the field has is set to "NOT NULL" we can assume a default value of NULL means that the default value is either empty or set to the MySQL default value for that field type.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Show create table tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have easily query-able schema information available to an application, I would suggest using the MySQL `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database.  The database provide query-able metadata tables that should meet your needs in your case, you are probably interested in the `COLUMNS` table.  You might query it like:

```
SELECT * FROM COLUMNS WHERE `TABLE_NAME` = 'your_table' AND `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'your_database'
```

Of course you need to consider limited the access privileges of the database user associated with your application, as you may not want them to see the entire `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` if there are other applications running (though this user would obviously be able to see information about other databases on the `COLUMNS` table).

Comment: Yes I considered that but the issue is doing the actual comparison in PHP code.  Sorry I realize I did not mention this in the original question.  I updated the question with this information.  Using "SHOW CREATE TABLE" basically just gives a big string that I would have to parse out perhaps with a well designed regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information.  Do you know how that might work on shared web hosts?  The application in question is distributed and often installed on shared web hosts.  Is the information schema available in cases such as this?

Comment: @atdev In cases like that you will probably find that that each individual host account has a MySQL user account associated with it that will not allow for access to common metadata such as this.